# Change a date column in multiple data frames with one function

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, lapply

I know there are several questions regarding the "apply one function to multiple data frames"-issue. However, I coundn't find a solution to my problem but I think I got close to it using a solution from this question:
[Same function over multiple data frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002838/same-function-over-multiple-data-frames-in-r?rq=1)

I have 12 data frames with 4 columns each. The second one contains the data as an integer (e.g. 20161014, so %Y%m%d).
To get it into 2016-10-14 I used

```
 TX_SOUID100758.txt[,2]<-as.Date(as.character(TX_SOUID100758.txt[,2]), "%Y%m%d")
```

Since I want to apply this function on all 15 data frames I tried

```
zch_filelist <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.txt")
for (file in zch_filelist){
  assign(file, read.csv(paste(path, file, sep=''),na.strings = -9999))
}
lapply(zch_filelist, function(x) (as.Date(as.character(x[2]), "%Y%m%d")))
```

I used the previously created list of file names when I imported the files into R.
However, it is not working. I guess the mistake is the indexing in the as.date function.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to use ?mapply.

Comment: thanks, but how do I addess the second vector in each data frame?

Comment: your zch_filelist should be a list in order to use lapply.

Comment: ok, now my data frames are in a list. but how do I address the second column in each data frame? 'lapply(zch_data[[]][,2], function(x) (as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d")))' does not work..

Comment: you can use this: `lapply(listofdf, function(x) (as.Date(as.character(x[,2]), "%Y%m%d")))`.

Comment: Since this has been answered, ought to be closed as no longer reproducible.