# Applying function to specific columns of dataframes in list

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes with common columns that I need to merge, but I need to coerce certain columns to character type first prior to merging. To fix this, I wrote the following:

```
master_list <- lapply(master_list, function(x) x %>%
                     mutate_at(.vars = vars(master_list$x$'send date',
                                            master_list$x$'send time',
                                            master_list$x$'Monthly',
                                            master_list$x$'InteractionEventDate'),
                               .funs = as.character))
```

However, when I look at these columns in any one dataframe in my list, the change was not made (e.g. InteractionEventDate is still a double), despite no error being thrown by the above line of code. I based it partially on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059050/apply-function-to-certain-columns-of-all-dataframe-in-list-and-then-assign-value) post, which used the now deprecated mutate_each.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a bit roundabout here. So maybe first define a function using `dplyr` logic and then lapply it over the list?

```r
premerge <- function(df){
            df %>%
               mutate_at(.vars = c("send date","send time", "Monthly","InteractionEventDate"), .funs = as.character)                        
              }

lappyl(master_list,premerge)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but get this following: "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x The column `send date` doesn't exist."

Comment: @The_Dude do ALL data frames have this column?

Comment: ah that was the issue. I had some empty dataframes in my list, and your suggestion works now after removing them.

Comment: @The_Dude glad to help.