# Mean of rows using column index number and create new variable for multiple data frames

Tags: r, mean

I have multiple data frames, for each of them I want to get the mean of every row and create a new variable. I want to calculate the mean using specific columns, because all data frames have the same variables, and the variables I want to calculate the means are not in sequence in the data frame, I am using the columns index number.

I am just creating some data frame here for an example, the ones I am actually using are larger than these ones.

```
mt1 <- matrix(c(1:50), nrow=5)
mt2 <- matrix(c(51:100), nrow=5)
mt3 <- matrix(c(101:150), nrow=5)
df1 <- data.frame(mt1)
df2 <- data.frame(mt2)
df3 <- data.frame(mt3)

dfs<-list(df1,df2,df3)
```

I tried to use a similar code from [Same function over multiple data frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002838/same-function-over-multiple-data-frames-in-r) but it did not work. Here is what I tried to do and the errors I got:

Code 1)

```
lapply(dfs, function(x) { x$mean <- rowMeans(x[1,2,3,8,9,10]); x})

Error in `[.data.frame`(x, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10) : 
unused arguments (7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Code 2)

```
lapply(dfs, function(x) { x$mean <- rowMeans(select(1:3,8:10)); x })

Error in UseMethod("select") : 
no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I am not sure what it is the issue. So any help or suggestion how I can do that is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `c`oncatenate.

```
lapply(dfs, function(x) {x$mean <- rowMeans(x[c(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10)]); x})
```

Maybe it's a little nicer using `transform`.

```
lapply(dfs, \(x) transform(x, mean=rowMeans(x[c(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10)])))
```