# How do I create a new dataframe in R with repeated values and calculations from a previous dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Dose, Num.Infected, Num.Uninfected
0.2      1            5
0.3      2            4
0.4      3            3
```

I would like to create a new frame that scores each infected individual as "1" and each uninfected individual as "0" for each dose size. I would like the new dataframe to look like this:

```
Dose, Score
0.2     1
0.2     0
0.2     0
0.2     0
0.2     0
0.2     0
0.3     1
0.3     1
0.3     0
0.3     0
0.3     0
0.3     0
0.4     1
0.4     1
0.4     1
0.4     0
0.4     0
0.4     0
```

I tried to write a for loop to go through each row but I wasn't able to do this properly. I'm not sure how to get the new dataframe to store repeated values from each row and then generate the new scores.

Answer (score 4):

Use `rep` to repeat a value x times and `dplyr::reframe` to create the new columns by group:

```r
library(dplyr)
reframe(df, Score = c(rep(1, Num.Infected), rep(0, Num.Uninfected)), .by = Dose)
```

```r
   Dose Score
1   0.2     1
2   0.2     0
3   0.2     0
4   0.2     0
5   0.2     0
6   0.2     0
7   0.3     1
8   0.3     1
9   0.3     0
10  0.3     0
11  0.3     0
12  0.3     0
13  0.4     1
14  0.4     1
15  0.4     1
16  0.4     0
17  0.4     0
18  0.4     0
```

This is the data I used:

```r
df <- read.table(header=T,text="Dose Num.Infected Num.Uninfected
0.2      1            5
0.3      2            4
0.4      3            3")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have several datasets that I need to do this for. How can I write a for-loop to go through all of those datasets, create new dataframes for those scored values and then save the new dataframes in a folder?

Comment: That's probably worth another question, but check existing answers for that matter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22002838/13460602. Create a list of the data.frames and use `lapply` is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 4):

If **base R** is a requirement, using `mapply`

```
data.frame(
  Dose =  with(df, rep(Dose, Num.Infected + Num.Uninfected)), 
  Score = as.vector(mapply(\(x, y) c(rep(1, x), rep(0, y)), 
                      df$Num.Infected, df$Num.Uninfected)))
   Dose Score
1   0.2     1
2   0.2     0
3   0.2     0
4   0.2     0
5   0.2     0
6   0.2     0
7   0.3     1
8   0.3     1
9   0.3     0
10  0.3     0
11  0.3     0
12  0.3     0
13  0.4     1
14  0.4     1
15  0.4     1
16  0.4     0
17  0.4     0
18  0.4     0
```